# C# textfile create / remove spacing of texts in same line

Tags: c#, text-files, spacing

what can I do to achieve the output on right side as shown on image? Do note that later on there will be many data with this kind of inconsistent alignment and is there any way to loop all text along with adjusted alignment as shown on right side of image?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: `string result = string.Join(" ", input.Split());`

Comment: To expand on @RufusL's feedback, the idea is that you'll `Split()` your input into an array, and then rejoin it with a space using `Join()`. What he left out, is you'll likely need to do `Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` to instruct it to a) split based on a space delimiter, and b) discard empty items in the array caused by duplicate spaces. There are also approaches using regular expressions for resolving this, but the `Split()`/`Join()` approach is faster.

Comment: `string result = string.Join(" ", input.Split().Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)));` also works to remove the empty entries. `Split` with no arguments will split on all whitespace characters.

Comment: @Rufus-l: On hindsight, you should have made this an answer—even though, I imagine, it wasn’t enough information to merit one. The accepted answer instead uses RegEx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Regex to replace occurrence of multiple whitespace (2 or more,including tab) with a single whitespace. For example,

```
var result = Regex.Replace(str,"[\t ]{2,}"," ");
```

The common forms of whitespace could divided into

- Space
- Tab(\t)
- NewLine(\n)
- Return(\t)

In the above scenario, it looks like you need to replace all the Space (2 or more) and Tab characters with a single whitespace character (and ignore the NewLine/Return characters). For the purpose, you could use Regex as shown in the code above

Comment: It works :DDDD, thanks pal your solution is simple and effective.

Comment: It's worth noting that @Rufus-L's solution in the comments is considerably faster than a regular expression, and not that much longer—though it might be slightly less intuitive to read if you're not familiar with the approach.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer, use Trim() or TrimEnd, but here is the way I would do your task using my Nuget package you can convert this to string.Split() if you don't want to use a Nuget package:

Nuget Package: 
DataJuggler.Core.UltimateHelper (.Net Framework)

DataJuggler.UltimateHelper.Core (.Net Core)

.Net Framework is shown

```
        // source input
        string inputFileText = "blah            blah              blah    blah  blah   " + Environment.NewLine + "blah blah            blah    blah blah";

        // parse the lines
        List<TextLine> lines = WordParser.GetTextLines(inputFileText);

        // If the lines collection exists and has one or more items
        if (ListHelper.HasOneOrMoreItems(lines))
        {
            // Iterate the collection of TextLine objects
            foreach (TextLine line in lines)
            {
                // Get the words
                List<Word> words = WordParser.GetWords(line.Text);
            }
        }
```

Then you can do what you want with each Line, and each Line contains a list of Words (string text).

Here is the code the Nuget package uses, if you would rather copy it:

```
        public static List<TextLine> GetTextLines(string sourceText)
        {
            // initial value
            List<TextLine> textLines = new List<TextLine>();

            // typical delimiter characters
            char[] delimiterChars = Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray();

            // local
            int counter = -1;

            // verify the sourceText exists
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sourceText))
            {
                // Get the list of strings
                string[] linesOfText = sourceText.Split(delimiterChars);

                // now iterate the strings
                foreach (string lineOfText in linesOfText)
                {
                    // local
                    string text = lineOfText;

                    // increment the counter
                    counter++;

                    // add every other row
                    if ((counter % 2) == 0)
                    {
                        // Create a new TextLine
                        TextLine textLine = new TextLine(text);

                        // now add this textLine to textLines collection
                        textLines.Add(textLine);
                    }
                }
            }

            // return value
            return textLines;
        }

        public static List<Word> GetWords(string sourceText, char[] delimeters = null, bool allowEmptyStrings = false)
        {
            // initial value
            List<Word> words = new List<Word>();

            // typical delimiter characters
            char[] delimiterChars = { ' ','-','/', ',', '.', '\t' };

            // if the delimter exists
            if (NullHelper.Exists(delimeters))
            {
                // use these delimters
                delimiterChars = delimeters;
            }

            // verify the sourceText exists
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sourceText))
            {
                // Get the list of strings
                string[] strings = sourceText.Split(delimiterChars);

                // now iterate the strings
                foreach(string stringWord in strings)
                {
                    // verify the word is not an empty string or a space
                    if ((allowEmptyStrings) || (TextHelper.Exists(stringWord)))
                    {
                        // Create a new Word
                        Word word = new Word(stringWord);

                        // now add this word to words collection
                        words.Add(word);
                    }
                }
            }

            // return value
            return words;
        }
```

Comment: This is a _lot_ of code to do something that can be done in one line with RegEx or a `Split()`/`Join()`. The NuGet package you put together may have a lot of other benefits and if someone is already using it then it might be a useful approach. But otherwise, this feels like trying to fit a square peg in a round hole.

Comment: That is why its a Nuget package. Only a few lines of code to get a list off Text Lines and Words, and words are trimmed, so need for regex.

Comment: There’s no need for regex in the answer from the original comments. Nor for introducing a third-Party dependency. And it’s _still_ less code. What does your approach offer above that?